# Adjust vertical position of single character in WordPress' Latex

Tags: latex, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to define a new operator (like `\bigominus` -- but it doesn't exist) to create an equation like

[image]

But the problem is that I can't shrink the lower indices after vertical aligning everything that follows. The code I have so far is

```
\mathop{\huge{\boldsymbol{\ominus}}}\limits_{\tiny{ijk}}\normalsize{\raisebox{0.7ex}{\text{x}[\,u\,][\,v\,][\,w\,]}}
```

If I remove `\raisebox{0.7ex}{}` it fixes the indices, but then the vertical alignment is gone.

[image]

Obviously it's noticeable with respect to the horizontal line of the symbol. Does anyone know how I may fix this? I would like to either move the `\ominus` symbol down so that the horizontal line is aligned with the cross of the `\text{x}`, or the `\text{x}` and everything that follows so that it aligns with the horizontal line of the `\otimes`.

I've spent a few hours trying to solve this problem but I cannot seem to find the right command in the rather limited available set from WordPress.

Comment: Hi! Can you reference the _available set from WordPress_ and share some more about your environment?